# ActiveRecord: Get records where association's attribute is not null

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: `SocialMediaPost` and `Metric`. A `SocialMediaPost` `has_many :metrics` and a `Metric` `belongs_to: :social_media_post`. I'm trying to write a query to select all `SocialMediaPost` where `metrics.short_link IS NOT NULL`.

A post can have between 1-3 metrics. When I run the following query, it returns `[]` when I would expect an ActiveRecord relation object consisting of several posts.

```
SocialMediaPost.includes(:metrics).where.not(metrics: {short_link: nil})
```

How can I adjust my query to capture what I'm looking for?

Comment: Your code looks pretty good and leaves me wondering if the generated query is incorrect. Can you please post the SQL query from `SocialMediaPost.includes(:metrics).where.not(metrics: {short_link: nil}).to_sql`. Also, posting the rows from `social_media_posts` and `metrics` which you expect to match the query might be helpful.

Comment: Here is the generated sql: `SELECT \"social_media_posts\".* FROM \"social_media_posts\"  WHERE (\"metrics\".\"short_link\" IS NOT NULL)`. I'm not sure if this was a fluke, but when I ran the same query today it returned the expected result (along with the same deprecation warning from my comment on Yang's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SocialMediaPost.includes(:metrics).where("metrics.short_link IS NOT NULL")
```

And for Rails > 4.0

```
SocialMediaPost.includes(:metrics).where.not('metrics. short_link' => nil)
```

Comment: That returns a `[]` along with a deprecation warning: `DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one of: social_media_posts, metrics) that are referenced in a string SQL snippet.`